# How to use discord.py in order to get audit log entries and analyze the data inside of it

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot that gets audit log entries and prints them out to me, but I have no clue how to go about it.

This is what I have so far:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import time

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

for entry in discord.Guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.ban):
    print(f'{entry.user} banned {entry.target}')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}.  Ready to go.')

client.run(token)
```

It throws this error:
`TypeError: audit_logs() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

I've read the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=audit_logs#discord.Guild.audit_logs), but I am still no closer to solving this.

How do I get this bot to read each entry made into the audit log and then print it out to the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the audit logs of the guild that a command has been invoked in, you should access through context, so use this:

```
@client.command()
async get_bans(ctx):
    async for entry in ctx.guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.ban):
           print(f'{entry.user} banned {entry.target}')
```

If you want to get a specific guild's audit logs you can use:

```
async for entry in client.get_guild(guild_id).audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.ban):
       print(f'{entry.user} banned {entry.target}')
```